# Combining various annotation metrics to score genes?

Tags: r, z-score, bioinformatics

A novice question.

I want to score each gene based on the net score for a set of annotation variables in the columns.

My aim for scoring the gene is gain an indication to the level of its impact/relevance/contribution to cancer overall.

Some of these variables describe presence absence as 0 and 1 (e.g. Oncogenes, TSG, HPV_overexpressed), others describe quantities/number of times the gene was observed (mutationaLoad, cancerAssociation, OMIM_GAD_diseases_sum) and others describe gene expression scores (cancerUnderexpression_z-scores_sum).

The problem is, simply summing the entries for each gene would over-emphasis the mutationalLoad contribution to the final score and would not accommodate the nature of the different measure described the number (presence/absence, gene expression, quantities). My hunch is the columns need to be scaled or recomputed so they can be cross-comparable.

What is the logic to follow to 1) achieve the cross-comparability of the columns and 2) to generate the final score for each gene. Any guidance to the general direction of combining scores will be appreciated.

I will use R to implement the scoring strategy.

````
geneName    Oncogenes   TSGs    MutationalLoad  GeneEssentiality_High_fitness   GeneEssentiality_Low_fitness    cancerOverexpression_z-scores_sum   cancerUnderexpression_z-scores_sum  CancerAssociation   HPV_overexpressed   HPV_underexpressed  EBV_overexpressed   EBV_underexpressed  OMIM_GAD_diseases_sum
p53 0   1   718 1   0   11.66702    0   6   0   0   1   0   423
ATM 0   1   165 0   0   0   -14.150254  3   1   0   0   1   53
Rb  0   1   157 0   0   0   -12.589082  4   0   1   0   1   22
NLRP3   0   0   132 0   0   1.584744    0   0   0   0   1   1   22
CycB    1   0   88  0   0   0   -2.607878   0   1   1   1   0   0

```
````

Comment: Interesting problem! There are many ways to summarize the columns. How do you want to interpret this gene score? Or what is its purpose?

Comment: The more I think about it, it is really an interesting problem. These variables fall under what I call cancer and disease association. Hence, the final tally of the genes is supposed to provide an indication to the level of its impact/relevance to cancer association.

Comment: What is the outcome or characteristic that you want this "score" to represent? There are many ways to combine such information, so you need to think precisely about just what you are trying to accomplish. Please provide that information by editing your question instead of commenting, as comments are easily overlooked and can be lost. Also, be very careful with these data, as HPV- and EBV-related cancers are biologically distinct from other cancers. A generic model of "cancer" that doesn't take that into account will be of limited usefulness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try the first principal component of the correlation matrix. In R that would be

```
prcomp(data, scale. = TRUE)$x[,1]
```

Because of the argument `scale.=TRUE`, R will use the correlation matrix. This is similar to normalizing each column (by subtracting its average and dividing by its standard deviation, see [Standard Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)#Examples)) and summing them, but principal components will make another linear combination of the columns such that it reflects the strongest correlation pattern. This method is often used for dimension reduction and if one feels that too much information is thrown away, one can consider also the second, third or next principal components.

There is no guarantee that this score will be a meaningful indicator of cancer, so there has to be something extra that shows that this is a good gene score. If the first principal component turns out to not seem very useful,  I suggest that you could try

- normalize every column with the Standard Score and sum them
- try other dimension reduction techniques

If you had a target that you wanted this gene score to predict, you could obtain a gene score by using the predicted values of a regression. Perhaps the variable `CancerAssociation` could be general enough for this.